# How to add managed wifi API to the working project

Tags: c#, nt-native-api

I'd *apologize* because of the question , in advance.

I'm a little newbie on C# , and I don't know how to use **Managed WiFi API** and how to add the classes to the working project, anyone helps me ?

I've downloaded the **Managed WIFI API** library and there are some type of classes and other things, but I don't know how to use them.
The ***Interop.cs,ManagedWifi.csproj,WlanApi.cs*** and finally ***AssemblyInfo.cs*** classes are available, could you help me to use them ?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NuGet, here is the package for WIFI api:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/managedwifi/

If you didn't use NuGet before see this link

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Answer (score 0):

What you've downloaded is a pre-compiled project that owns its assembly references and classes.

What you should add to your project is the class named **WlanApi.cs** and use this on your project , when you compile the project the appropriated assembly reference is created then it's supposed to work properly.